# Installing FVWM in Arch Linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox, xorg, arch-linux, fvwm

I recently successfully installed Arch Linux in VirtualBox, for the first time. I want to install FVWM, so I installed X Server, and then ran `pacman -S fvwm`. It says that fvwm has been installed, but the terminal still stays there and there is no windowing. I know I am probably doing something stupid, but I'm not sure what. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

**Update:** I installed GDM. When I select "fvwm" in the menu and enter my password, the screen turns black, several console messages with a green "okay" status to the left appear, the screen goes black again, and then it turns gray and returns to the login screen.

Comment: What happens if you run `startx`? If that does not work, post your `/usr/bin/startx` file.

Comment: @terdon: When I run `startx`, the screen goes black and resizes, but then nothing happens and ctrl-c doesn't work. I have reboot through the virtualbox menu.

Comment: @terdon: I see the `/usr/bin/startx` and I am able to access it through nano, but I am not sure how to post it since I just installed Arch.

Comment: Just check if there is an `exec fvwm` line at the end, there shouldn't be, but just in case. Try what MariusMatutiae suggests, if that fails, just add `exec fvwm` to the end of `startx`. Oh, and Ctrl+Alt+Backspace should let you exit after you've run startx.

Comment: Neither of the suggestions worked. Also, when I run `startx` still goes black, and `Ctrl+Alt+Backspace` doesn't work. I get the error `xauth: timeout in locking authority file /home/cloudcoder2000/.Xauthority`. It pops up 3 times, then I see several output messages, and then finally the screen goes black.

Comment: I just got the same black screen again, and I didn't power off this time. After a few minutes, the error message `No protocol specified` popped up several times, then the message `xinit: giving up` then `xinit: unable to connect to X server: Resource temporarily unavailable` followed by `waiting for X server to shut down (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.` and then ` xinit: server error` and finally ` xauth: timeout in locking authority file /home/cloudcoder2000/.Xauthority`. It then returns to a terminal line.

Comment: Is this after a fresh reboot? It sounds like there is another X session running or one crashed. Have you read through [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/FVWM)?

Comment: I re-installed X Server and rebooted. `startx` works properly when I run `sudo startx` but still goes to the blank black screen when I only run `startx`.

Comment: Compare `/root/.xinitrc` and `$HOME/.xinitrc`. Also, try deleting your `~/.Xauthority` file in case you've changed its permissions or something. It will be recreated next time you try to log in.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11049/discussion-between-cloudcoder2000-and-terdon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your `$HOME` directory is owned by `root` (the OP pasted this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11664430#11664430)):

```
$ ls -l /home 
total 20 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 13 18:38 cloudcoder2000 drwx------ 2 root root
```

So you don't have write access to your `$HOME` which means that X cannot create a `$HOME/.Xinit` file and that is giving you the error you see. The following commands should fix it:

```
sudo rm ~/.Xauthority
sudo chown cloudcoder2000:cloudcoder2000 ~/
```

You can now add this line to your `~/.xinitrc` (this command will create the file if it does not exist):

```
echo "exec fwvm" >> ~/.xinitrc
```

Now, running `startx` should start an `fwvm` session.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to start FVWM in Arch is to add the line "exec fvwm" to your .xinitrc file, then restart the VM. Did you try that? Or: you should see it in the "Sessions menu" at login, if you use either kdm or gdm (I think...). Did you check this